# How to move cursor without Bookmarking in tinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, bbcode

I am trying to integrate your editor to phpbb. I want to move cursor between empty bbcode just after insertion. for example click on a [bbbcode] button to insert [bbbcode][/bbbcode] to editor.

when I use bookmarking:

```
ed.selection.setContent('[bbbcode]');
p = ed.selection.getBookmark();
ed.selection.setContent('[/bbbcode]');
ed.selection.moveToBookmark(p);
```

this will remove last part ( [/bbbcode] ) from the final source when I POST it.
editor shows last part but when post content to server last part ( [/bbbcode] ) is missed because of bookmark moving.

is there any way to move cursor with bookmarking?

I would like to insert [bbbcode][/bbbcode] and move cursor here: 
[bbbcode]here[/bbbcode]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should insert something like `[bbbcode]<span id="marker">.</span>[/bbbcode]`.
After insertion you select and remove the span-element:

```
var $marker = $(ed.getBody()).find('#marker');
tinymce.activeEditor.selection.select($marker.get(0) );
$marker.remove();
```